# MongoDB self join(aggregation) of collection with parent references

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Hello I have this collection, with parent references, I need to do self join on this collection, so that output will contain the children to maximum depth in one document and also get the output based on ***"Type"*** field.

```
{ 
    "DescId" : "1", 
    "Desc" : "Testing", 
    "ParentId" : "null", 
    "Order" : 1.0, 
    "Type" : "A", 
    "Parent" : null
}

{ 
    "DescId" : "1.1", 
    "Desc" : "Testing Child 1", 
    "ParentId" : "1", 
    "Order" : 1.0, 
    "Type" : "B", 
    "Parent" : "Testing"
}

{ 
    "DescId" : "1.2", 
    "Desc" : "Testing Child 2", 
    "ParentId" : "1", 
    "Order" : 2.0, 
    "Type" : "B", 
    "Parent" : "Testing"
}

{ 

    "DescId" : "1.1.1", 
    "Desc" : "Testing grand child 1", 
    "ParentId" : "1.1", 
    "Order" : 1.0, 
    "Type" : "C", 
    "Parent" : "Testing Child 1"
}
```

At present I have this output based on answer given to my previous question:

```
{ 
    "ADescId" : "1", 
    "ADesc" : "Testing"
}
{ 
    "BDescId" : "1.1", 
    "BDesc" : "Testing child 1"
}
{ 
    "BDescId" : "1.2", 
    "BDesc" : "Testing Child 2"
}
{ 
    "CDescId" : "1.1.1", 
    "CDesc" : "Testing grandchild 1"
}
```

I have tried doing $graphlookup aggregation on this collection, somehow data seems to get messed up. Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this. Thanks.

Desired output:

```
{ 
    "ADescId" : "1", 
    "ADesc" : "Testing",
    "BDescId" : "1.1", 
    "BDesc" : "Testing child 1",
    "CDescId" : "1.1.1", 
    "CDesc" : "Testing grandchild 1"
}
{ 
    "ADescId" : "1", 
    "ADesc" : "Testing",
    "BDescId" : "1.2", 
    "BDesc" : "Testing Child 2"
}
```

Comment: If you need joins you're after a relational database, not nosql database in the first place mate.

Comment: Well then, I will have to rephrase my question. I am looking at aggregation of documents in the collection I have.

Comment: I didn't mean the title. You're using wrong tools for the job, just saying.

Comment: I understood, but cannot help. Its part of application I am working on.

Comment: Do you have a limit on the number of nestings that are present in the documents? Like apart from A,B,C levels..

Comment: It will be till level E.

Comment: @VaniKulkarni how about 1.1.2 ? Do you expect to have one document per B level or cases like `1.1.1` and `1.1.2` should be displayed separately ?

Comment: @mickl: Yes it should be separate, like this :`{ 
    "ADescId" : "1", 
    "ADesc" : "Testing",
    "BDescId" : "1.1", 
    "BDesc" : "Testing child 1",
    "CDescId" : "1.1.2", 
    "CDesc" : "Testing grandchild 2"
}`

Comment: @VaniKulkarni IMO technically that might be possible but that aggregation pipeline will be too complex. Maybe you can use `$graphLookup` to get parent with it's children and then process that in application layer

Comment: @mickl: Ok,let me try to process it in application itself. Thank you.